# Why does Numeric treat unary differently to binary?

Tags: scala

What's up with this?

```
import Numeric.Implicits._

def myAdd[T: Numeric](x: T, y: T) = x + y   // Works
myAdd(1,2)

def myInc[T: Numeric](x: T) = x + 1   // Fails at x: could not find implicit value for parameter num: scala.math.Numeric[Any]
myInc(9)
```

Scala 2.10

Something to do with x+1 --> Numeric+Int?

Comment: Yes because if you remove `+ 1` or replace by `x + x` you'll see it compiles fine.

Answer (score 5):

So after looking at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.math.Numeric and seeing `one` and `fromInt`, I fiddle a bit in the REPL and came up with:

```
scala> def myInc[T: Numeric](x: T) = x + implicitly[Numeric[T]].fromInt(1)
myInc: [T](x: T)(implicit evidence$1: Numeric[T])T

scala> myInc(9)
res1: Int = 10

scala> def myInc[T: Numeric](x: T) = x + implicitly[Numeric[T]].one
myInc: [T](x: T)(implicit evidence$1: Numeric[T])T

scala> myInc(9)
res2: Int = 10
```

It is not related to it being a method with one argument, but instead on the compiler inferring the `T` type as `Any`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, common type for `Int` and `Numeric` is `Any`.

Use this:

```
def myInc[T: Numeric](x: T) = x + implicitly[Numeric[T]].one
```

There is also `fromInt` member of `Numeric` you may find useful.

Comment: On "common type for Int and Numeric", note that in `x + 1` you don't have the type `Numeric` and `Int` for which the compiler find the common super type. `x` is of type `T` and `1` of type `Int`.